# Handle jquery ajax() error thrown when calling an api with blob response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an API using jax-rs that returns an InputStream of a pdf.

```
        try {
            //block of code to generate pdf

            InputStream pdfStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFilePath);

            return Response.ok(pdfStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + date + ".pdf")
                    .build();
        } catch (SQLException | CustomException | NullPointerException | IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ApiResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(ex.getMessage()).build();
        }
```

I did use a try-catch to handle error and return it as ***INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR***.

My problem is when I receive that response on an ajax, the ***jqXHR.responseText*** is undefined. How can I get the error message?

API call code:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: api,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "binary", 
            xhrFields: { responseType: "blob"  },
            success: function(response) {
                $("#loading-overlay").hide();
                $("#modal").modal("hide");
                
                var blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/pdf" });
                window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob), "_blank");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR) {
                $("#loading-overlay").hide();
                
                console.error(jqXHR.status + " - " + jqXHR.responseText, jqXHR);
                
                showError(jqXHR.status + " - " + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
```